# Different behavior for \" in C

Tags: c, string, char, string-literals

I have a strange problem when using string function in C.
Currently I have a function that sends string to UART port.
When I give to it a string like

```
char buf[32];
strcpy(buf, "AT+CPMS=\"SM");
strcat(buf, "\"");
uart0_putstr(buf);
//or 
uart0_putstr("AT+CPMS=SM");  //not a valid AT command, but without quotes just for test
```

it works well and sends string to UART. But when I use such call:

```
char buf[32];
strcpy(buf, "AT+CPMS=\"SM\"");
uart0_putstr(buf);
//or
uart0_putstr("AT+CPMS=\"SM\"");
```

it doesn't print to UART anything.
Maybe you can explain me what the difference between strings in first and second/third cases?

Comment: There shouldn't be any difference between all these calls. The function can't tell the difference between a string variable and a string literal.

Comment: @Barmar, I agree with you, but I see the fact that it works differently.

Comment: There must be something else going on. Especially the first and second cases are identical. There's no difference in the buffer.

Comment: Could the UART be sensitive to timing? You'll be accessing memory differently.

Comment: @Vitalii "it works well" is vague.  How was the success/failure determined?

Comment: Please copy/paste the actual code.

Comment: Could you try initializing the buffer array with `char buf[32] = { 0 };`? iirc, `strcat` adds a new null character at the end because it is supposed to change a string's length, while strcpy actually might not (not sure tho). Alternatively, you could use `strcpy(buf, "AT+CPMS=\"SM\"\0");` to make sure you have a null char at the end.

Comment: @TorgeRosendahl `strcpy` and `strcat` always nul-terminate the target string. We need a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), the shortest *complete* code that transmits those strings with the declared results.

Comment: @WeatherVane strcpy does "copy the string including the null character" as per the docs. Apparently, there was no null character at the en dof the string in this case.

Comment: @TorgeRosendahl then it wasn't a string, and passing it to `strcpy` or `strcat` is *undefined behaviour*.

Comment: @WeatherVane I agree with what you are saying, but what else could be the reason? Does strcpy accept uninitialized arrays? Will it initialize the array or will it write to a nullpointer?

Comment: @TorgeRosendahl without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it can only be speculation. I don't really know what you are asking. All the posted strings have a nul terminator, `strcpy` will probably seg fault if passed a `NULL` pointer, and there is no need for the caller to initialise the target string.

Answer (score 3):

**First the C language part:**

- **String literals:** All C string literals include an implicit null byte at the end; the C string literal `"123"` defines a **4 byte array** with the values 49,50,51,**0**. The null byte is always there even if it is never mentioned and enables `strlen`, `strcat` etc. to find the end of the string. The suggestion `strcpy(buf, "AT+CPMS=\"SM\"\0");` is nonsensical: The character array produced by `"AT+CPMS=\"SM\"\0"` now ends in two consecutive zero bytes; `strcpy` will stop at the first one already. `""` is a **1 byte array** whose single element has the value 0. There is no need to append another 0 byte.
- **`strcat`, `strcpy`:** Both functions always add a null byte at the end of the string. There is no need to add a second one.
- **Escaping:** As you know, a C string literal consists of characters book-ended by double quotes: `"abc"`. This makes it impossible to have simple double quotes as *part* of the string because that would end the string. We have to "escape" them. The C language uses the backslash to give certain characters a special meaning, or, in this case, suppress the special meaning. The entire combination of backslash and subsequent source code character are transformed into a single character, or byte, in the compiled program. The combination `\n` is transformed into a single byte with the value 13 (usually interpreted as a newline by output devices), `\r` is 10 (usually carriage return), and `\"` is transformed into the byte 34, usually printed as the `"` glyph. The string `Between the arrows is a double quote: ->"<-` must be coded as `"Between the arrows is a double quote: ->\"<-"` in C. The middle double quote doesn't end the string literal because it is "escaped".

**Then the UART part:** [The internet makes me believe](http://www.learnerswings.com/2014/03/atcmgd-at-command-to-delete-sms-message.html) that the command you want to send over the UART looks like `AT+CPMS="SM"`, followed by a carriage return. The corresponding C string literal would be `"AT+CPMS=\"SM\"\r"`.

The page I linked also inserts a delay between sending commands. Sending too quickly may cause errors that appear only sometimes.

The things to note are :

- The AT command syntax probably demands that `SM` be surrounded by quotes on both sides.
- Additionally, the protocol probably demands that a command end in a carriage return.

Answer (score 2):

This ...

> ```
> char buf[32];
> strcpy(buf, "AT+CPMS=\"SM");
> strcat(buf, "\"");
> ```

... produces the same contents in `buf` as this ...

> ```
> char buf[32];
> strcpy(buf, "AT+CPMS=\"SM\"");
> ```

... does, up to and including the string terminator at index 12.  I fully expect an immediately following call to ...

> ```
> uart0_putstr(buf);
> ```

... to have the same effect in each case unless `uart0_putstr()` looks at bytes past the terminator or its behavior is sensitive to factors other than its argument.

If it *does* look past the terminator, however, then that might explain not only a difference between those two, but also a difference with ...

> ```
> uart0_putstr("AT+CPMS=\"SM\"");
> ```

... because in this last case, looking past the string terminator would overrun the bounds of the array, producing undefined behavior.

Comment: @Vitalii where does the `uart0_putstr` function come from? Assuming that it is the one from the AVR library, it should send single characters until a NULL char is found in the string. [[lib implementation](https://github.com/jnk0le/AVR-UART-lib/blob/master/usart.c#L604)]

Answer (score -1):

Thanks all. Finally It was resolved with adding NULL char to the end of string.

Comment: Do you mean after the one that was already there?  That would imply that the function was indeed looking past the string terminator, at least by one byte.  Possibly, then, it consumes input in two-byte or larger units.  But that's something that I would very much expect to be documented.  I'm glad your program is working, but I'm skeptical about the solution having been what you say, if in fact the code presented in the question is representative.